# In VSCode, how to apply single quotes on python files, not only to typescript, with prettier?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, single-quotes

Why is single quotes applied to typescript, but not to python files? I have prettier installed, but when I save a file, the .ts files are automatically formatted and single quotes is applied, but .py files are not. I have in settings.json file this setting:

`"prettier.singleQuote": true,`

and I see it is applied to angular files, but not to python files.

Comment: The data you shown looks like in json format. If you are serializing the data using json's dump or dumps, remember json do not support single quotes. It converts them to double quotes.

Comment: @MSH I am not talking about json. I am talking about python code. Angular code is formatted, but python code doesn't get formatted. That is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Prettier extension only supports [these languages](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettier-formatter-for-visual-studio-code):

```
JavaScript · TypeScript · Flow · JSX · JSON
CSS · SCSS · Less
HTML · Vue · Angular
GraphQL · Markdown · YAML
```

Does not include `python`.

And you can find, if you select `Format Document With...` in the python file, it will not list the Prettier.

Comment: I think it is true. I use in VSCode from now Black, which formats python fine. So, prettier I will use for other languages, but not for python. Thanks anyway for noticing that.